# TypeError: Cannot read property '4' of undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following code.

It is for automatizing a spreadsheet that gets new rows from an MIT Inventor App. I wrote the following code but in when I ran the script it shows the following message:

TypeError: Cannot read property '4' of undefined

This is the code:

```
function automatized() {

 const consumptionIndex = 3;
 const kWhIndex = 4;

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var sheetData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 var row = sheet.getLastRow;
 var lastcolumn =sheet.getLastColumn();

 if( sheetData[row-1][kWhIndex] == 0) {return;}
 sheetData[row-1][consumptionIndex] = sheetData[row-1][kWhIndex] - sheetData[row-2][kWhIndex];
sheet.getRange(row,1,1,lastcolumn).setValues([sheetData[row-1]]);
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Photo of code is not acceptable here. Please read [mcve]  and [ask]

Comment: getLastRow``()``